# Como obter o número de linha afetadas em um insert no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Em SQLServer eu uso após o `insert` ou `update` eu uso:

```
SET @LINHAS_AFETADAS = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Assim obtenho o número de linha afetadas, gostaria de saber qual o equivalente em MySQL, pesquisei na web mas só encontrei soluções em códigos, preciso que seja feito direto na `query`, tentei `ROW_COUNT()`, mas essa função retornou `0` para nenhuma linha afetada e `-1` para 1 ou mais linha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação oficial do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count), o `SELECT ROW_COUNT()`, é o que funciona.

Se você está testando no MySQL Workbench, pode ser que isso pareça não funcionar, conforme [este comentário](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4306151/2290538).

Na [documentação também há essa observação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count):

> Important
>
> ROW_COUNT() is not replicated reliably using statement-based replication. Beginning with MySQL 5.1.23, this function is automatically replicated using row-based replication. (Bug #30244)

Comment: Obrigado Fernando, realmente eu estava testando no MySQL Workbench ,na aplicação o ROW_COUNT() funcionou conforme esperado.

Comment: @André, fico feliz por ter ajudado. Notei que você é novo por aqui. Então, se as respostas sanaram suas duvidas completamente, em relação a pergunta, por favor marque a resposta que melhor lhe ajudou como resposta, e também pode dar votos positivos, nas demais respostas que lhe ajudaram. E se ainda restam duvidas edite a pergunta com as mesmas, ou comente nas respostas.